# LINQ to SQL: Change timestamp forcefully of a table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, timestamp

I am using LINQ to SQL and require some help in updating a timestamp column in a table.

```
Car candidate = Context.Cars.Where(c => c.CarID == car.Id).SingleOrDefault();
candidate.CarName = carToUpdate.CarName;
candidate.CarDescription = carToUpdate.CarDescription;
candidate.IsActive = carToUpdate.IsActive;
candidate.IsCab = carToUpdate.IsCab;
candidate.StockTypeId = carToUpdate.StockTypeId;
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

If there are no changes in the properties of the car entity, the timestamp is not changed.
(Looks like LINQ to SQL is intelligent enough to not send an update to database).

Is there anyway to forefully change timestamp from LINQ to SQL??

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Wouldn't a trigger on the SQL table be an option?</strike>

**EDIT:** I think this thread answers your question [force LinqToSql to submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076174/force-linqtosql-to-submit)

Comment: Because LINQ to SQL is not sending any update statement to database,the trigger is never going to get called. There should be a some way to forcefully send that update statement to database.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You WANT to update the timestamp. I thought the timestamp column was never updated at all. I will try to think of a different solution.

Comment: Have a look at my revised solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a LastUpdatedDate column and setting that to `DateTime.Now` , that should ensure it will always do an update and will then change your timestamp column.

Comment: I thought of it but that would be my last option. The LastUpdatedDate column will be dummy and will be no use other than this.

Comment: If I do an update on database using T-SQL, the timestamp is changing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is don't.

If the entity's properties are the same after you modify them as they are when you pulled the entity out of the db, it hasn't actually changed.

What's the purpose of forcing a new timestamp to generate when the row was in fact not updated?

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through [Object States and Change-Tracking (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386982%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and it states:

> You can detect Updates by observing
>   notifications of changes.
>   Notifications are provided through the
>   PropertyChanging event in property
>   setters. When LINQ to SQL is notified
>   of the first change to an object, it
>   creates a copy of the object and
>   considers the object a candidate for
>   generating an Update statement.
>
> For objects that do not implement
>   INotifyPropertyChanging, LINQ to SQL
>   maintains a copy of the values that
>   objects had when they were first
>   materialized. When you call
>   SubmitChanges, LINQ to SQL compares
>   the current and original values to
>   decide whether the object has been
>   changed.

Would you be able to create a partial class that adds a property that calls `PropertyChanging` to update a the property that isn't mapped and so only exists in code?